# how do I get the images in my folder to appear in my javascript index?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a news page in Javascript where every article is on a card. Every card has a headline, an image and the author's name. The headlines show up fine, but the images are broken and the author names don't show up at all. My code looks like this:

```
function cardCreator(e) {

    const cards = document.querySelector('.cards-container');
function cardCreator(e) {

const card = document.createElement('div');
card.classList.add('card');

const headline = document.createElement('div');
headline.classList.add('headline');
headline.textContent = e.headline;
card.appendChild(headline);

const author = document.createElement('div');
author.classList.add('e.author');
card.appendChild(author);

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.classList.add('img');
author.appendChild(container);

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = e
container.appendChild(img);
const span = document.createElement('span');
author.appendChild(span);
span.text = `By ${author}`

cards.appendChild(card);

return card;
```

}

I thought it was the img src, but if I change out the e the whole page breaks so I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing related to images in this code.  How is this code relevant?

Comment: Where is `span` declared?  Where is it added to the card?

Comment: Assuming e is an object, you probably want to pass whatever the image source is to the img tag. Right now you're assigning the object to src.

Comment: `author.classList.add('e.author');` is adding a class, not text. `img.src = e` what is e ? Should it be something like `img.src = e.src`?